# Controller return String "index", instead of redirect to index.jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

i am trying to make web app with spring boot, i've spent much time, looked many posts and articles, and still can't make redirect to my jsp, what am i doing wrong?. That's i have:

my project structure (I can't post image):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7CYR.png

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

spring.session.store-type=none

spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://localhost/phonebook?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username:root
spring.datasource.password:root
spring.datasource.driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQl:debug
```

class WebMvcConfig:

```
@Configuration
//@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new      InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

Controller :

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String index() {
   return "index";
}
}
```

SpringBootApplication :

```
//@Configuration
//@ComponentScan
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class PhoneBookApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PhoneBookApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

---

After deleting `@ResponseBody` from my Controller I got this exception:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Comment: delete `@ResponseBody` from your `MainController` if you want to return index.html

Comment: i am trying to redirect to index.jsp. I've deleted @ResponseBody, and got:  
 
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Try to change your application like this:

You dont need to have a `WebMvcConfig` class for using template resolver for `jsp`. You configure the suffix and prefix correctly in your `application.properties` file. So delete this class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PhoneBookApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PhoneBookApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PhoneBookApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
       return "index";
    }
}
```

You dont need a `template` folder in your `resource` folder and the dependency in your pom, if you dont use thymeleaf as template enginge. You can delete

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I've deleted dependency "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf", and it's work! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `@ResponseBody` from the controller method in order to dispatch the view (index.jsp), otherwise the response will be returned as part of the http body.

> @ResponseBody Annotation that indicates a method return value should
>   be bound to the web response body.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html

Comment: i did it. now i have an error: 
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this **application.properties:**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
enter code here
```

Also, Remove it from Controller  **@ResponseBody**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
   return "index";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, i'm deploying a A**ngular application with Spring MVC API**.

So the other solutions were not working for me, So i used `servlet-mapping` from the `web.xml` file.

Here is example of the Servlet and its Mappling in the web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The web.xml file need to be placed in the Web-INF directory.

Here is the structure of the `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app>
... Your configurations
</web-app>
```